# How could I use the variables from a remotely stored JavaScript file within the function of another JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

Currently, I'm trying to take an array from a JavaScript file stored on a web page (ex. "website.com/javascript.js") and run it through a function stored in a JavaScript file I have made for a website. This is for a game.

Previously, I was attempting to import both .js files into the HTML file and use the array from the website as an input for my own JavaScript file, but I couldn't seem to do this.

I simply couldn't find the answer online (or didn't know how to phrase the question right). If I need to import anything for the purpose of doing this, could you tell me what to import? Thank you!

Here's the code I'm working on. Sorry for the very novice code, I haven't worked much in JavaScript.

```
function makeBracket(players){
    var resultString;
    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
       var assassinName = players[i][1];
       var targetCode = players[i][4];
       for(var j=0;j<players.length;j++){
            var code = players[j][2];
            if(code == targetCode){
                var targetName = players[j][1];
                document.write(assassinName + " -> " + targetName + "<br>");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you're working on. It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I provided the code, as requested. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Please be mindful when tagging your questions.  This is all about external JavaScript files and functions so I see no reason why this question was tagged with [tag:html] or [tag:jquery].

Comment: @Sparky both can be used to load javascript files

Comment: @RenatoZannon, and so can PHP, but that's not an appropriate tag here either.  Tags are supposed to reflect the relevant content of the question, not a laundry list of loose connections.

Comment: @Sparky Ok, good point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be using the `function.js` for the file that contains your function, and `array.js/array.json` for the file that contains the data you need.

### Using a global variable

You could include both files, and expose the array on the first file as a global variable.
To include them, use two `script` tags on your HTML, in order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/array.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/function.js"></script>
```

`array.js`:

```
window.myArray = [/* Data here */];
```

`function.js`:

```
var array = window.myArray;
doStuff(array);
```

### Loading via AJAX

An alternative is to store the array in [JSON](http://json.org/) format, and load it asynchronously using AJAX.

Consider the following `function.js`:

```
$.getJSON("/array.json", function(array) {
  doStuff(array);
});
```

When loaded (I'm assuming jQuery here, since it is in the tags of the question), it will make a request to `/array.json`, parse it as JSON, and pass the results to the callback function. From there, you can do anything with the data.

An advantage of this method is that you don't need to worry about ordering the files anymore, and you don't use any global variables. However, it is slightly more complex to understand, and there'll be a small delay between the page loading and the data arriving.

Comment: The question is more geared towards how I can import the Javascript file at "website.com/javascript.js", and from there implementing the methods you explained. So how would I go about "including both files"?

Comment: @user3487036: can you load both scripts using `<script>`?

Comment: @user3487036 I tried to expand the answer, let me know if it is better now